# How to read file from remote server without FTP, using php?

Tags: php, ftp, smb

First I want to read a file with path

$file = readfile("\10.96.5.94\DIR\README.txt");

It is giving error no such file directory exists.

I have also tried fopen and file_get_contents functions.

Which I am able to access from my php server.

10.96.5.94 is just a file server, from which I want to read a file, and attach it in mail.

Is it possible to directly attach file by reading it from server?

Or I need to copy it on server and attach it?

Comment: A file server as in samba?  Of course you can't read it like that unless \10.96.5.94\ is a directory on your server.  You would atleast need to specify a protocol.

Comment: I was updated by my server admin that I may try SMB protocol, can we connect to network pc using SMB protocol in PHP?

Comment: According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php, no, SMB is not a supported protocol within PHP.  You may be able to use an extension but you'd have to do some searching.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get read file from other server.

Whatever file you want to read, you must have to give full server path as the the file,

for example see below lines.
My following line is not working proper if i haven't give a proper path.
`$a = file_get_contents('google.com');` - Not working proper
`$a = file_get_contents('google.com');` - Not working proper.

Instead write following lines to get proper results,

`$a = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');` - It works good. So try this way.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but its just a simple PC on my network, which does not have any domain. 
Let me tell you exact scenario, 
Its like my PDF file is generated at on storage with IP 10.96.5.94, I just want to read that file from my php application installed at another network pc eg. 10.96.2.24, and send it in mail via attachment. is it possible?

Comment: Yes bro, still you need to give full server path.

Comment: But then I am unable to access the file with " h t t p ://10.96.5.94 "  also. Its giving error failed to open stream.

Comment: Try this one bro. This will work perfectly to you
`$file = readfile("http://10.96.5.94/DIR/README.txt");`
http://10.96.5.94  =>  your server URL,
DIR => your folder, README.txt => your file

Comment: Warning: `readfile(http://10.96.5.94/BHW_repo_new/README.txt)`: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\wamp\www\ytest\ebill\readfile.php on line 3
Code : 
`$server = "http://10.96.5.94/";
$filename = $server."BHW_repo_new/README.txt";
$file = readfile($filename);`

Comment: Ok. great. Let me know your file path.